# Generic function returns type of <unknown> when using an interface that's decoupled from the target type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a hook in React which returns the value from an rxjs observable, but without a hard dependency on the rxjs library.

So I created a general interface which describes a portion of the observable object's API that I will interact with.

```
export interface GenericSubscribable<T> {
  subscribe: any
}

export const useObserverable = <T>(
  s: GenericSubscribable<T>
): T => { 
  // the points don't matter
  return {} as any
};
```

However when consuming it

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs'

const counter = interval(1000) // Observable<number>
const shouldBeNumber = useObserverable(counter)
```

`shouldBeNumber` comes up as `<unknown>` rather than `<number>`.
Why is this the case?

[Example of type inference working in a similar scenario](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpisBZUHsC2EYAFqAOYA8AKgHzIDeAUMi8gG5wA2ArhAFzIqzVrgDWAgM4ZyjAL6NGMbiGzBcINNOzUaACg49+ggJQD0mbHkIlyOhsJZQi3KBqasP7LrwA0Dz2ICAORiQf7y8gqgkLCIKADiECDQWFZEpCCUtPYeBrwCQpFKKmBqGgBiUASJyRY6uhICNSkIaTaZOqaCOaxOYC4aEgB0eRByCowI6lLIEgTp5MgAvJoWYLpBEsS43JwAJgBCEObkQcaT02DIZEQAklcrldVJLQ3z7WTGQA)

Comment: Shouldn't you be declaring the generic type: `const shouldBeNumber = useObserverable<number>(counter)`? I'm a little unclear as I don't know what interval actually is.

Comment: I'm trying to take advantage of type inference from generics. Sorry interval is from rxjs and returns `Observable<number>`

Comment: What you are doing here is not isomorphic with the example you provide. Note that in the example, `Strict` is passed a string type argument and returns an object that matches the interface `StrictSomething<string>`. But in your case, you pass `useObserverable` an object of type `Observable<number>` which returns an object of type T, not a generic object which takes a generic parameter of type `Observable<T>`. 

To show you the correct code, it is important to know what `useOberverable` actually does. Do you mean to subscribe to the observable or expose the subscribe method?

Comment: Given that you expect a number back from useObservable, I imagine you wish to subscribe inside the useObservable function. In that case you will need to set the type of subscribe in `GenericSubscribable` to match the type of  the subscribe function (it is `(observer?: PartialObserver<T>) => Subscription`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @see sharper for the insight. I was looking at the wrong value
The following example works

```
export interface GenericSubscribable<T> {
  subscribe: (cb: ((value: T) => any)) => any
}

export const useObserverable = <T>(
  s: GenericSubscribable<T>
): T => { 

  return {} as any
};
```